# Uploadcare: how to get uploaded file from openDialog?

Tags: javascript, uploadcare

My scenario - I would like to open an upload dialog from my own button and get the uploaded file info. In Uploadcare JS version 0.12 I did the following:

```
$(".upload-image-button").on("click", function() {
  uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
    imagesOnly: true
  }).uploadDone(function(info) {
    setImage(info.cdnUrl);
  });
});
```

In 0.16 there's no more `uploadDone` and all it does is return a promise without any data. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uploadDone` was never part of public API and was not mentioned in [documentation](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/javascript_api/), so it was removed. `uploadcare.openDialog` always returns promise object with selected file (or group of files for multiupload dialogs). But file is promise itself: it resolves when uploading is complete. So to access uploading info you should subscribe to `file.done`:

```
$(".upload-image-button").on("click", function() {
    uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
        imagesOnly: true
    }).done(function(file) {
        file.done(function(fileInfo) {
            setImage(fileInfo.cdnUrl);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @AlexanderShtuchkin Does above exact code work for multi uploads?

Comment: @bart, this will not work for multi-upload, this may help: https://kb.uploadcare.com/article/213-how-to-get-individual-file-uuids-from-a-multiupload